# Unhandled exception error inspite of catching in a catch block

Tags: exception

I get an unhandled Exception type error for the following code, even though, as I understand it, I have handled the exception in the catch block.

```
class NewException extends Exception{
private String msg;
public NewException(String msg){
    this.msg = msg;
}
public String getExceptionMsg(){
    return msg;
}}
class CatchException {
public static void method () throws NewException{
    try {
        throw new NewException("New exception thrown");
    }
    catch (NewException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getExceptionMsg());
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("In finally");
    }
}}
public class TestExceptions{
public static void main(String[] args){
    CatchException.method();
}}
```

Comment: You print the exception.You don't get it as you say.

Comment: I agree with @Cratylus, when you execute `e.printStackTrace()` it will look like you got an exception in your IDE/command line tool, but you actually didn't.

Comment: @Cratylus,@FlorianMinges: I am not sure I understand. How is what I am doing different from this example from Thinking in Java: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ311_005.htm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `method()` declares that it throws `NewException`. Whatever is inside that method is irrelevant:

```
public static void method () throws NewException{
    //...
}}

public static void main(String[] args){
    CatchException.method();
}}
```

The compiler sees that you are calling `CatchException.method()` in `main()` and that you are not handling it in any way (either catching or declaring `main()` to throw `NewException` as well. Thus the error.

The compiler doesn't care if you are actually throwing that exception or not. Have a look at [`ByteArrayInputStream.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#close%28%29) - there is no way it'll ever throw an `IOException` - but you still have to handle it since it's declared.